# My images and glyphicons are not showing, my paths are right though, how can I solve this problem?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to add an image to my navbar and a glyphicon to the logout button, but none of these are showing up.

The upper navbar is what my navbar is looking like right now, beneath this navbar is the navbar it's supposed to look like.

[image: This is what the navbar is looking like right now]

[image: This is what the navbar has to look like]

[image: This is the code and file structure of the project]

Edit: [image]

Comment: Glyphicons have been dropped in Bootstrap 4, what version do you use?

Comment: @Erez.S I'm using bootstrap 4, is there an alternative to these glyphicons?

Comment: You can use both Font Awesome and Github Octicons as a free alternative for Glyphicons. (Use google to specific links)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glyphicons have been dropped in Bootstrap 4 (The version that you currently use).

You can use both Font Awesome (https://fontawesome.com/) and Github Octicons (https://github.com/primer/octicons) as a free alternative for Glyphicons.

Also, as Eliseo suggested, you can use the own bootstrap icons: https://icons.getbootstrap.com

Comment: or the own bootstrap icons: https://icons.getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Thanks! Added to answer

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the "glyphicon" as stated in the comments it is no longer supported by bootstrap 4, as an alternative i would suggest using [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/) or [Bootstrap Icons](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/)

For the second question (the image not showing), a small change need to be done to the image path, this will do the trick: `<img src="../images/logo_vesta.png"/>`
the addition of `../` before the "images" folder means that you need to exit the current folder "Header" before entering the "images" folder.

Comment: it's still not working and showing the sort of placeholder image.

Comment: could you show us the content of the "Header" and "images" Folders please?

Comment: I added an image of these folders to the original post :)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 has dropped support for Glyphicons. This is the reason glyphicons are not showing up on your website. You can use other freely available icon libraries such as Google Material Design Icons and Font Awesome to use.

As for the image, I don't think you are including the correct source to the image. The 'images' folder is one level up in the directory that you're currently working on. So, the correct source for the image should be:

```
<img src="../images/logo_vesta.png" alt="logo">
```

Including the above image tag should do what you're trying to achieve.