# Angular and bootstrap

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I'm pretty new in Angular and I'm trying to use `Bootstrap` in my projects. I've installed bootstrap with `npm` like this:

```sh
cmd npm install bootstrap --save
```

and imported the root in my `style.css`:

```css
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

and next I've tried to use an icon available in bootstrap with this code:

**star.component.html**

```html
<h2> Trying to use bootstrap</h2>
<span class="glyphicon" [class.glyphicon-star]="isFavorite" [class.glyphicon-star-empty]="!isFavorite" (click)="onClick()">
</span>
```

and this is my component.ts file:

**star.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-star',
    templateUrl: './star.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./star.component.css']
})
export class StarComponent implements OnInit {
    isFavorite: boolean;



    onClick() {
        this.isFavorite = !this.isFavorite;
    }
}
```

In addition, everything is imported in `app.module` in this way:

```js
import { StarComponent } from './star/star.component';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ....
        StarComponent,
    ],
    ...
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I have no errors but I cannot see the `star`. (I've also tried to import in bootstrap: `[ AppComponent, StarComponent ]` but it doesn't work.

in my `package.json` I can see I'm using bootstrap version 4.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63670494/no-glyphicons-and-no-images-showing/63670593?noredirect=1#comment112590596_63670593

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you installed the `bootstrap 4` (latest version) and glyphicons are not supported in `BS4` anymore.

> Bootstrap 4 does not have its own icon library (Glyphicons from Bootstrap 3 are not supported in BS4). However, there are many free icon libraries to choose from, such as Font Awesome and Google Material Design Icons.

It's better to use Font Awesome icons.

Visit this link on [W3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_icons.asp#:%7E:text=Bootstrap%204%20does%20not%20have,and%20Google%20Material%20Design%20Icons.) for more information about it.

Comment: Thanks so much. Solved downgrading from 4 to 3.

Comment: Just don't use font-awesome in dynamically generated lists with icons on each row. The performance is terrible. It took over 30 seconds to load a couple hundred rows with per-entry icons on each row using font-awesome. With glyphicons it took only 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Glyphicons are not included by default in bootstrap 4.

> While you won’t find a built-in icon library in Bootstrap, our separate Bootstrap Icons projects is a growing set of open source SVGs you can use. While they’re designed first and foremost to work with our components and documentation, you can use them in any project.

Glyphicons were only available by default in bootstrap 3 but were removed in bootstrap 4. Consider installing FontAwesome or any other icon library